# ViewCell - image fill, text on bottom

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The layout i want is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmLcv.jpg

I want the image (illustrated with the color green) to fill the entire layoutcontol. On top of image positioned at the bottom with full width i want a textbox/label to put a title. The title view should have a black semi-transparent background.

This is the best i've got (the code below), but it has a few issues:

#1 - The text doesnt wrap like it is suppose to. It just cuts the sentence, like the rest is going off screen.

#2 - The image doesnt scale to the width of the container.

```
        Label lblTitle = new Label()
        {
            BackgroundColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.8),
            LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap,
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label))
        };
        lblTitle.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "headline");

        Image imgBanner = new Image()
        {
            /*
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
            Aspect = Aspect.Fill
            */
        };
        imgBanner.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "ImageUrlSource");


        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(lblTitle, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional | AbsoluteLayoutFlags.WidthProportional);
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(lblTitle, new Rectangle(0, 1, 1, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));

        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(imgBanner, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.SizeProportional);
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(imgBanner, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1));

        AbsoluteLayout layout = new AbsoluteLayout()
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
            Children = 
            {
                imgBanner,
                lblTitle
            }
        };

        View = layout;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Grid instead.

```
    Label lblTitle = new Label()
    {
        BackgroundColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.8),
        LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap,
        FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label))
    };
    lblTitle.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "headline");

    Image imgBanner = new Image()
    {
        /*
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
        Aspect = Aspect.Fill
        */
    };
    imgBanner.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "ImageUrlSource");

//=========== Addition Start Here ============//

    Grid grid = new Grid();
    grid.RowDefinitions = 
    {
        new RowDefinition{ Height=new GridLength(200,GridUnitType.Absolute) },
        new RowDefinition{ Height=new GridLength(30,GridUnitType.Absolute},
    }

    grid.Children.Add(imgBanner,0,1,0,2); //two rowspan
    // == .Add(imgBanner,column,column+columnspan,row,row+rowspan)

    grid.Children.Add(lblTitle,0,1,1,2);  //one rowspan

View = grid;
```

Comment: This fixes the positioning of the text relative to the image - but the image still doesnt streatch/fit properly. Do you have a suggestion to how I could go about doing that? Making it fill horizontal and fit vertically? And the text doesnt wrap either. It just goes off screen if there isnt enough room. I've been playing around with using GridUnitType.Auto instead of Absolute to make it fit the content instead, but without any luck...